# ADS4249 from Texas Instruments output clock

Tags: adc, texas-instruments

The ADS4249 supports both LVDS and LVCMOS outputs. It has an input clock (CLKP) and an output clock (CLKOUTP). The input clock can be a LVCMOS or LVDS signal. My question is does the output clock depend on the input clocks signal type?
Lets say my input clock is LVCMOS can I still choose LVDS for the output clock?

datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads4249.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1602449719072&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet says:

> **8.4.1.1 Output Interface**
>
> Two output interface options are available: double data rate (DDR) LVDS and parallel CMOS. They can be selected using the serial interface register bit or by setting the proper voltage on the SEN pin in parallel configuration mode.

Comment: Ok. I guess the input clock doesn't matter. thanks